# WordPress site is not working after moving from staging to live server

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a site in WordPress and moved the site from staging to live server.After moving the site it is not displaying anything when i open the URL.But i am able to access admin panel and all but not showing the pages data in front end.

Comment: Any errors in your console? 
Try to activate debbuging for wordpress. To enable debugging you need to open the file wp-config.php of your WordPress installation and set define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ).

Comment: @Kalti yes i have done that but not displaying any errors after changing the debug to true as well.The same site is working fine in my staging server

Comment: @Kalti i am using a plugin WP Bakery visual editor if i deactivate the plugin its working fine but when i activate the plugin it is not displaying anything

Comment: does the problem also occur if you only activate WP Bakery and all other plugins are de-activated? Maybe this link contains some usefull information: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/ (deactive all plugins, change themes, ...)

Comment: I have deactivated  that plugin then the site is displaying if i activate the plugin the site is not visible

Comment: @Kalti deactivated the plugins and checked by activating one by one its resolved thank you